# terraform aws_lb: The subnet ID '$element(aws_subnet.public_subnets.*.id,count.index)' does not exist

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, devops

I am a little confused about the proper way to setup an ALB.  Initially i wanted to simply create an instance and add it behind an alb, then later add new instances when needed...but the exception i recieve when applying my scripts tells me

> At least two subnets in two different Availability Zones

Now i've added two sets of private and public subnets in two different zones.  When i go to apply the script -  now get an error:

> InvalidConfigurationRequest: A load balancer cannot be attached to multiple subnets in the same Availability Zone

These two things seem contradictory to me - but that is probably because im not very much of a network person.  Wondering if someone can explain? here is some code (since i know its frowned upon to just ask questions without any code)

Variable definitions:

```
variable "public_subnets" {
  type = map(number)
  #we'll use the cidrsubnet function with the number below to create the subnet ip range
  default = {
    "us-east-1a" = 1
    "us-east-1b" = 2
  }
}

variable "private_subnets" {
  type = map(number)
  #we'll use the cidrsubnet function with the number below to create the subnet ip range
  default = {
    "us-east-1a" = 3
    "us-east-1b" = 4
  }
}
```

And this is how im creating the subnets:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnets" {
  for_each                = var.public_subnets
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.vpc.cidr_block, 4, each.value)
  availability_zone       = each.key
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  tags                    = merge({ Name = "${var.name}_public_subnet_${each.value}" }, var.tags)
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnets" {
  for_each          = var.private_subnets
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  cidr_block        = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.vpc.cidr_block, 4, each.value)
  availability_zone = each.key
  tags              = merge({ Name = "${var.name}_private_subnet_${each.value}" }, var.tags)
}
```

And this is what my alb module looks like (alb_subnet_ids is all subnet ids):

```
resource "aws_lb" "alb" {
  name                       = "${var.name_prefix}-alb"
  internal                   = false
  load_balancer_type         = "application"
  security_groups            = [var.alb_sg_id]
  subnets                    = var.alb_subnet_ids
  enable_deletion_protection = false
  tags                       = merge({ Name = "${var.name}_alb" }, var.tags)
}
```

Is it a true statement that you cannot and SHOULD NOT attempt to balance between multiple subnets in a single zone?
Any best practice reading recommendations for this sort of thing - how to properly script/setup a network with an ALB?
My goal is to be able to add a scaled up instance manually when needed(without ASG).  so i figured an ALB would be ideal for minimizing impact.

Comment: What is `var.alb_subnet_ids`?

Comment: its all subnet_ids -> public and private.  So i think there in is the problem as for a given zone there is a public and private and im adding both to the alb.  i just am not clear why its an issue

Comment: ALB creates nodes in the subnets you specify. I guess you cannot have more than one node in the same AZ for the same ALB.